# Using ISO8601 Dates in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-format

I’m pretty experienced with other SQLs (PostgreSQL, Microsoft Server, MySQL, SQLite), but not so in Oracle.

Is there any way to get Oracle to accept date literals in ISO8601 format. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    when DATE
);
INSERT INTO data(name,when) VALUES ('Fred','2021-10-05');
--  ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a73691c72c1d3c96cdf0762199160fa).

Surely there must be as switch.

The same would apply to outputting dates: is there a way of ensuring ISO8601 formatted dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle supports the ANSI date literal

```
INSERT INTO data(name,when) VALUES ('Fred',date '2021-10-05');
```

If you want to rely on implicit data type conversion of strings to dates and dates to strings, that is controlled by your session's `nls_date_format`

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

If you do that, your string will be implicitly converted to a `date`

```
INSERT INTO data(name,when) VALUES ('Fred','2021-10-05');
```

and any queries you run will implicitly convert the `date` to a string in the ISO format.

```
select * from data;
```

Generally, however, it is frowned upon to rely on implicit conversion because someone else may connect to your database and specify a different setting for their session and then you'll get errors or incorrect conversions.  You'd generally want to prefer explicit conversions from one data type to another.

Comment: Thank you, that’s what I was looking for. I have to say, with my limited experience, I have never found Oracle to be obvious compared to the others.

Comment: I just re-read your comment about implicit conversion. I should have thought that if someone else connects to the same database, their session would be independent of yours. Wouldn’t that allow two different users to have different date formats without breaking anything?

Comment: @Manngo - Sure.  The problem comes when you have a stored procedure or some other piece of code that depends on implicit conversion.  That procedure might work perfectly for the user that connects and sets his `nls_date_format` to the expected value and then fail for a user that chooses a different `nls_date_format`.  If you always specify conversions explicitly, you won't have code that functions differently based on the `nls_date_format`.

Comment: That makes sense. In a script it’s safer to use explicit conversion, while in a hands-on session it’s OK to set `nls_date_format`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_date('2021-10-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: Is there no way to get Oracle to accept the original date literal without a conversion function?

Comment: Depending on the client, eg. environment variables can be used.